# Get value from DataGridView on form load

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, datagridview

I am trying to get a value fro a DataGridView 'DGV' when my winform loads ie, Forms2_load. DGV is bound and I am using the code below to Fill the DGV.

My question is, how do I get a value from 'DGV' without any user intervention, just when the form loads. I tried a for next loop on the form load event, but no message pops up. Can someone please help with this. Thanks

```
Me.CustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StorageDataSet1.Customers)

Dim values As String

    For Each RW As DataGridViewRow In DGV.SelectedRows
        'Send the first cell value into messagebox'
        values = RW.Cells(0).Value.ToString

    Next

MessageBox.Show(values)
```

Comment: You are using SelectedRows which is empty on form load (no selection has been performed yet). Better try with Rows.

Comment: I have tried Rows, but the messagebox is empty so I assume no value is being retrieved. Thanks

Comment: If you replace `DGV.SelectedRows` with `DGV.Rows` and there is no-blank entries in, at least, one row of the first column in `DGV`, `values` would be not blank. This is the maximum I (or anyone else) can say with the information your are providing. `RW.Cells(0).Value.ToString()` is fine. If it does not return any value it would mean that there is no value to be returned.

Comment: I'm not sure your datagrid will contain any entries at this point. Normally the update of the DGV will happen after your leave the function (Bindings will reset somewhere). I would have looped through the StorageDataSet instead if I were you. Alternatively you run the fill code line in the constructor (which I think will work).

Comment: Could you please provide an example WozzeC as I am fairly new to VB.NET  and still learning my way through. Thanks

Comment: @WozzeC the effects from modifying the DataSource might be reflected in the DGV right away. It depends upon the exact configuration. In any case, the OP is extremely unclear and does not even seem to be able to debug the code properly; and thus any suggestion is just a blind shot. The OP should make an effort to make the problem (the exact code) much more clear such that reliable help can be provided.

Comment: @varocarbas You are correct. For all we know that adapter might not even be connected to the DataGridView. More code or info is needed. What happends when you set a breakpoint on the foreach row and hover the DGV and select Rows?

Comment: :@WozzeC Thank you for your suggestion. Helped me understand the logic better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might get better results if you use the bindingsource that the DGV is connected to.  It will get a CurrentChanged event only after its loaded or when the position moves.

```
Private Sub BindingSource(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles BindingSource.CurrentChanged
    Dim oVw As DataRowView
    oVw = TryCast(BindingSource.Current, DataRowView)
    If Not oVw Is Nothing Then
        MessageBox.Show(oVw.Item(0).ToString)
        '
    End If
End Sub
```

This will trigger each time the DGV moves to a new position.  Change the name to whatever your BindingSource is.